# HQL select from multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

This query:

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT substring(a.account, 1, 6), a.ref, b.event_id, substring(a.admin, 1, :adminLength) FROM Parent a, Child b WHERE b.joinString = a.joinString AND b.event_id=:eventId AND substring(a.admin, 1, :adminLength) LIKE :admin AND a.date BETWEEN :from AND :to");
```

Produces a SQL statement that works in MySQL.

However, when I loop through the Child `List` I get `java.lang.ClassCastException` on the line `for (int j = 0; j < allParent.get(i).getAllChild().size(); j++) {` of this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allParent.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(allParent.get(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < allParent.get(i).getAllChild().size(); j++) {
           System.out.println("Child: " + allParent.get(i).getAllChild().get(j).getID());
    }
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().clear();
}
```

**Parent.hbm.xml**

```
<bag name="allChild" table="child" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key property-ref="surname">
        <column name="surname" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.test.Child" />
</bag>
```

Is there a way I can run this statement using `Criteria` (or something else) instead and have it populate both `allParent` `List` and `allChild` `List` linked to each `Parent` within `allParent`?

Comment: Is child_id the string variable  and also it would be more helpful for us if you show your Model classes

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the model classes, my best guess would be that you want to replace 'AND child_id = :childId' with 'AND child.id = :childId', or whatever the id column is labelled in your Child class.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using projection in HQL your result will be List. So, for each resultant row you have an Object[] array with following data types as per your projections. **{String, Your model object, int/long, String}**. So, when you do `allParent.get(i).getAllChild()` and `i=0` you are doing `getAllChild()` on `Object[]` array and will result `ClassCastException`.

Please go through using projections in HQL.

Comment: Is there a way I can run this statement using `Criteria` (or something else) instead and have it populate both `allParent` `List` and `allChild` `List` linked to each `Parent` within `allParent`?

Comment: Perhaps I could configure my `Parent.hbm.xml` mapping differently?

Comment: HQL or Criteria you can get parent along with all it's children by joining the child with parent. And in HQL keep parent alone in projection to iterate over parent list. Then you won't expect any ClassCastException.